# Can a heavy Stored Procedure wait another SP to finish?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an application that inserts information to a SQL Database. Then it has to run a heavy stored procedure. The issue is that when I have more than 2 or 3 call to this SP it begins to throw errors.

What i did to avoid this problem was to add a flag to a table like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 File_Key FROM File WHERE Flag_Value = 3)
    BEGIN
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 File_Key FROM File WHERE Flag_Value = 1)
        BEGIN

        DECLARE @LocalFile_Key int = (SELECT TOP 1 File_Key FROM File WHERE Flag_Value = 1)

        UPDATE File
        SET Flag_Value = 3
        WHERE File_Key = @LocalFile_Key

        File Process...

        Update File
        Set Flag_Value = 2
        Where File_Key = @LocalFile_Key
    END
END
```

But I still can see that sometimes 2 store procedures get running which is very weird. And when the store has a problem it left the Flag_Value '3' so it locks the stored procedure.

Comment: You should wrap the SP in a transaction with the appropriate isolation level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you encountered concurrency problem. you could lock execution of concurrent procedure by app lock. in the begin of procedure lock by [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) and at the end of procedure release the lock by [sp_releaseapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx) and when the procedure called it get lock and another concurrent called procedure should wait until called procedure at first release the lock.

add this block in the begin of procedure.

```sql
DECLARE @result int;
EXEC @result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'ProccessFileProc', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';
IF @result < 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```

by this solution concurrent called sp wait another sp to finish.

Comment: So the code will stop at the Exec @result line and wait until lock is released??

Comment: sp1 was called so it has the lock, then sp2 is called when it reached to get lock it should wait until sp1 release the lock.

Comment: are this answer was useful Bernardo Isidro Guerrero ?